# A Confusing task

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, probability

> 

My approach to the problem was as follows-

```
a=[ ]
for i in range(7):
    a.append([0]*7)

c=dict()
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        a[i][j]=(i,j)

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        c[i+j]=tuple((i*j+j+c))

print c
```

But this produces:

```
{0: (0, 0), 1: (1, 0), 2: (2, 0), 3: (3, 0), 4: (4, 0), 5: (5, 0), 6: (6, 0), 7: (6, 1), 8: (6, 2), 9: (6, 3), 10: (6, 4), 11: (6, 5), 12: (6, 6)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step by step way to do this would be

```
pairs = {}
for first in range(1,7):
    for second in range(1,7):
        total = first + second
        if total in pairs:
            # If sum exists, add this tuple to the list for this key.
            pairs[total] += [(first,second)]
        else:
            # If sum doesn't exist, start a new list for this key
            pairs[total] = [(first,second)]
```

Result

```
>>> pairs
{2: [(1, 1)],
 3: [(1, 2), (2, 1)],
 4: [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)],
 5: [(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)],
 6: [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)],
 7: [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1)],
 8: [(2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2)],
 9: [(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 3)],
 10: [(4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4)],
 11: [(5, 6), (6, 5)],
 12: [(6, 6)]}
```

Since this sounds like an academic exercise I assume you cannot use some of the pre-existing Python modules. Otherwise, you may want to check out [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). The former can handle the "does this key exist yet or not?" and the latter can handle combinations to remove your nested `for` loops.

Comment: I Do not want the probability sir.. I want the combinations in a dictionary...Please read the question Again !!!!

Comment: See my edit. And calm down, you dont need to type in ALL CAPS or use !!!!! on your sentences. Relax and ask your questions and comments calmly please.

Comment: Sorry Cyber...i have an exam tomorrow so i panicked.....Thanks for your explicit  and perfect answer:)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
combinations = {}
for a in range(1, 7):
    for b in range(1, 7):
        combinations.setdefault(a+b, []).append((a, b))
```

Result:

```
{2: [(1, 1)],
 3: [(1, 2), (2, 1)],
 4: [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)],
 5: [(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)],
 6: [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)],
 7: [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1)],
 8: [(2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2)],
 9: [(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 3)],
 10: [(4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4)],
 11: [(5, 6), (6, 5)],
 12: [(6, 6)],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some standard Python utilities:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product
```

All numbers on a single dice:

```
numbers = range(1,7)
```

And now, for each combination, sum the combination and append the combination to the list for that combination:

```
reduce(lambda acc, comb: acc[sum(comb)].append(comb) or acc, product(numbers, numbers), defaultdict(list))
```

Resulting in:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {2: [(1, 1)], 3: [(1, 2), (2, 1)], 4: [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)], 5: [(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)], 6: [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)], 7: [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1)], 8: [(2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2)], 9: [(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 3)], 10: [(4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4)], 11: [(5, 6), (6, 5)], 12: [(6, 6)]})
```